# Efiling SOAP Webservices Error

Tags: java, soap, certificate, soap-client, jks

I'm trying to use a SOAP Client for E-filing application. Documentation for SOAP Client is provided [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fu3Tzvv3BqfaMqWGdnKXpV_9s-GC2_u5/view?usp=sharing).

When I try to run the client I get following error:

```
18:21:09,441 [ERROR] [org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature] [main] [computeSignature] [584] - [Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]]
org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:745)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:528)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:691)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:176)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.uploadBulkPan(Unknown Source)
    at bulkPanService.BulkPanService_Client.main(BulkPanService_Client.java:34)
18:21:09,447 [WARN] [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler] [main] [doSignBeforeEncrypt] [231] - [Sign before encryption failed due to : Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]]
18:21:09,449 [WARN] [org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils] [main] [doLog] [452] - [Interceptor for {http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditsecws}BulkPanService#{http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditsecws}uploadBulkPan has thrown exception, unwinding now]
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:233)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.uploadBulkPan(Unknown Source)
    at bulkPanService.BulkPanService_Client.main(BulkPanService_Client.java:34)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:585)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:691)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:176)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin.getPrivateKey(Merlin.java:745)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:528)
    ... 15 more
Invocation failed with the following: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot find key for alias: [<MY-ALIAS-NAME>]
```

In properties files, I'm providing

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=12345678
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password=12345678
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=MY-ALIAS-NAME
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=keystore/client/me.jks
```

I have generated the `.jks` file from `.cer` file using command

```
keytool -importcert -file PRIVATE_KEY.cer -keystore me.jks -alias MY-ALIAS-NAME
```

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Comment: PRIVATE_KEY.cer is a certificate file, not a private key. You need to import the private key

Comment: Hi, do you know what is the extension of private key? Is there a way to convert certificate file to private key?

Comment: .key or something similar. A .cer file does not contain a key so you can not convert it